# Definition of the function $f_{\epsilon_0}$ in the fast-growing hierachy

Tags: number-theory, ordinals, big-numbers

I found an article where the growth of

$$f_{\epsilon_0}$$

in the fast-growing-hierachy is described, but the text 
 is very long and difficult to understand.

Is

$$f_{\epsilon_0}(n)=f_{\omega^{\omega^...}}(n)$$ with n omegas

or something else ?

I think I understood the procedure upto

$$f_{\omega+1}(n)$$

but I already have difficulties to understand

$$f_{\omega^\omega}(n)$$

Can someone explain the procedure step by step, beginning with

$$f_{\omega+1}(n)\ ?$$

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Fast-growing_hierarchy#f.CE.B50.28n.29) might help.

Comment: I realize I am late, but to any trying to learn FGH, [these videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vq2BxAJZ4Tc&list=PLUZ0A4xAf7nkaYHtnqVDbHnrXzVAOxYYC) were quite helpful with the explanation of limit ordinals, fundamental sequences, and all that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The standard way of defining these sequences goes by assigning in an explicit fashion to each limit ordinal $\alpha$, for as long as possible, an increasing sequence $\alpha_n$ that converges to $\alpha$. Once this is done, we can define $f_\alpha$ by diagonalizing, so $f_\alpha(n)=f_{\alpha_n}(n)$ for all $n$.

Of course there are many possible choices of sequences, but one can argue that the standard choices are the natural ones. Here, we note first that if $\alpha<\epsilon_0$, then we can write $\alpha$ uniquely as $\omega^\beta(\gamma+1)$, for some $\beta<\alpha$. The ordinal $\alpha$ is limit iff $\beta>0$. In that case, we set $\alpha_n=\omega^\beta\gamma+\omega^{\beta_n}$, if $\beta$ itself is a limit, while if $\beta=\delta+1$ is a successor, then we set $\alpha_n=\omega^\beta\gamma+\omega^\delta n$.

The approach described above does not work when $\alpha=\epsilon_0$, since we would have ($\gamma=0$ and) $\beta=\alpha$. The natural choice here is to let $\alpha_0=0$ and $\alpha_{n+1}=\omega^{\alpha_n}$, so $\alpha_{n+1}$ is a tower of $\omega$s of length $n$.

With this convention in place, we can continue for a while. Eventually we reach again a point where we need yet another convention. The topic of [ordinal notations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_notation) studies ways of continuing the process for as long as possible. The goal is to be able to refer explicitly to (recursive) ordinals in inductive arguments, and the notations quickly become so complicated that we need stronger and stronger background theories to verify that the orderings they capture are in fact well-orderings.

---

The sequence of functions $f_\alpha$, defined by Löb and Wainer, sets $f_0(n)=n+1$, and  $f_{\alpha+1}(n)=f_\alpha^n(n)$, where the superindex denotes iteration, that is, $f_\alpha\circ\dots\circ f_\alpha(n)$, where $f_\alpha$ appears $n$ times. Finally, if $\alpha$ is limit, then we set $f_\alpha(n)=f_{\alpha_n}(n)$, as indicated above. As long as the choice of cofinal sequences is reasonable enough, we can verify that the resulting transfinite sequence of functions is strictly increasing, where for functions $f,g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, we set $f<g$ iff $f(n)<g(n)$ for all but finitely many values of $n$.

For as long as we have been able to define these functions (which means, for as long as our system of ordinal notations allows us), the $f_\alpha$ are recursive. The computation of the values $f_\alpha(n)$ depends directly on the complexity of the ordinal notation we use.

(This explains the choice of $\alpha_0=0$ rather than $1$ or $\omega$ for $\alpha=\epsilon_0$. This choice is picked so that the recursive functions provably total in the theory called $I\Sigma_{k+1}$ are eventually dominated by $f_{\alpha_{k+1}}$ for all $k$. Here, $I\Sigma_{k+1}$ is the sub-theory of first-order Peano arithmetic resulting from restricting the induction schema to [$\Sigma_{k+1}$ formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy).)

For example, $f_\omega(n)=f_n(n)$ and $f_{\omega+1}(n)=f_\omega^n(n)$. For example, $f_{\omega+1}(0)=0$, $f_{\omega+1}(1)=f_\omega(1)=f_1(1)=f_0^1(1)=f_0(1)=2$, $f_{\omega+1}(2)=f_\omega(f_\omega(2))=f_\omega(f_2(2))=f_\omega(f_1(f_1(2)))=f_\omega(f_1(f_0(f_0(2))))=f_\omega(f_1(f_0(3)))$ $=f_\omega(f_1(4))=f_\omega(f_0^4(4))=f_\omega(8)=f_8(8)$, etc. This is already a significantly large number.

To compute $f_{\omega^\omega}(n)$, we would start by noting $f_{\omega^\omega}(n)=f_{\omega^n}(n)$, so $f_{\omega^\omega}(0)=f_1(0)=0$, $f_{\omega^\omega}(2)=f_{\omega^2}(2)=f_{\omega2}(2)=f_{\omega+2}(2)=f_{\omega+1}(f_{\omega+1}(2))=f_{\omega+1}(f_8(8))$, etc. In practice, the computation of these functions is quite unfeasible.

For a last example of how hopeless this quickly gets, let's attempt to see how $f_{\omega^\omega}(3)$ would be computed. Let's write $\alpha\to\beta$, for $\alpha$ limit, to indicate that $\beta=\alpha_3$, so that $f_\alpha(3)=f_{\alpha_3}(3)$.

We have $\omega^\omega\to\omega^3\to\omega^23\to\omega^22+\omega3\to\omega^22+\omega2+3$, so that $f_{\omega^\omega}(3)=f_{\omega^22+\omega2+3}(3)$. In turn, to compute this we must compute $f_{\omega^22+\omega2+2}^3(3)$, which in particular leads us to compute $f_{\omega^22+\omega2+2}(3)$, for which we then need to compute $f_{\omega^22+\omega2+1}^3(3)$, which eventually leads us to compute $f_{\omega^22+\omega+3}(3)$, etc.

Similar computations for larger ordinals are even more cumbersome. For instance, with the same convention, we have
 $$\omega^{\omega^\omega}\to\omega^{\omega^3}\to\omega^{\omega^23}\to\omega^{\omega^22+\omega3}\to\dots\to\omega^{\omega^22+\omega2+2}2+\omega^{\omega^22+\omega2+1}2+\omega^{\omega^22+\omega2}2+\omega^{\omega^22+\omega+2}2+\omega^{\omega^22+\omega+1}2+\omega^{\omega^22+\omega}2+\omega^{\omega^22+3}\to\dots$$

One can check by induction that $f_1(n)=2n$, $f_2(n)=n2^n$, and $f_3(n)$ is already larger than a stack of powers of $2$ of length $n$. (Some authors define the sequence slightly different to ensure that $f_2(n)=2^n$ and $f_3(n)$ is precisely the stack of powers of $2$ of length $n$.) These functions form what we usually call a *fast-growing hierarchy*.

A while ago, I wrote a paper on Goodstein's function that required me to consider this sequence. You may find it [here](http://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/goodsteins.pdf).

Comment: How large is $f_{\omega^\omega}(3)$ approximately ? Can it be expressed using conway-chains ?

Comment: It is hard to compare the number with other expressions, as $f_{\omega^\omega}$ is well beyond the realm of primitive recursive functions. Its computation, started in the answer above, of course will eventually reduce to computing some $f_{n_1}\circ\dots \circ f_{n_m}(k)$ for some (enormous) finite integers $n_1,\dots,n_m$ and $k$. Since each finite level $f_n$ can be bounded using Conway's arrow notation, so can this number, but I have not carried out the computation to give you an estimate.

Comment: @Peter "How large is $f_{\omega^\omega}(3)$ approximately ? Can it be expressed using conway-chains ?" -- Apparently [$\ f_{\omega^2}(n) > C(n)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_numbers#Systematically_creating_ever_faster_increasing_sequences), where $ C(n) = n\rightarrow n\rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow n$ with $n$ arrows. Then $f_{\omega^\omega}(3) = f_{\omega^2 3}(3) > C_{\omega^2 2}(3)$, where $C_\alpha$ is the function in a new fast-growing hierarchy obtained by replacing the usual initial function (successor) by the function $C$. ...

Comment: ... I.e., $C_0(n) = C(n), C_{k+1}(n)={C_k}^n(n)$, etc. Note that even $C_1(3)$ is already a chain of inconcievably-many Conway arrows: $C_1(3) = C(C(C(3))) = C(C(3\rightarrow3\rightarrow3\rightarrow3))$, which is a chain whose argument is given by a chain whose argument exceeds Graham's number).

Comment: If I understood it right, $\large f_{{\omega^2+1}}(3)$ is already too large to be expressed with conway chains. I found lower bounds in the internet for $f_{\omega+1}(n)$ using BEAF, but I would like to have a lower bound for this in conways notation.

Comment: @Peter That may be a good new question to add. The only paper I'm aware of that looks for lower bounds of specific instances of fast growing functions is Paul Erdős, George Mills, *Some bounds for the Ramsey-Paris-Harrington numbers*, J. Combin. Theory Ser. A, **30 (1)**, (1981), 53–70. MR0607039 (84c:03099). It certainly would be interesting to be able to say something new about the $f_\alpha(3)$.

Comment: For sufficiently large n, $f_{\omega+1}(n)$ dominates Graham's sequence G(n), which is defined by $G(0) = 4$ , $G(n+1) = 3 \uparrow^{G(n)} 3$. In wikipedia, fast growing hierarchy, it is shown that $f_{\omega+1}(64) > G(64) = G$, so for n=64 G(n) is already catched up, probably earlier. What I could not proof so far is the inequality $2\uparrow^{n-1}n > 3\uparrow^{n-2}3 + 2$ used to proof this claim.

Comment: If $f_{\omega+1}(n) > G(n)$ does indeed hold for $n\ge k$ for some natural number k, this would be a nice lower bound and could be easily described with conway chains. I am curious which k is sufficient.

Comment: I am still interested in sharp UPPER bounds for the fast growing hierachy. Since $2^{n}n < 3^n$ , $3^n$ is an upper bound for $f_2(n)$. Can upper bounds for $f_k(n)$  be established based on this fact ?

Comment: @Peter Yes, but in a sense the bounds are not too sharp. For instance, for any $t>2$, $t^n$ is an upper bound for $n$ large enough. Of course, sharpness is hard to quantify precisely at this level.